# Show full HTML content in WinJS.UI.Pages

Tags: javascript, jquery, microsoft-metro

I use WinJS.xhr to get full HTML content from a website. The problem is I can't display it on WinJS.UI.Pages because it even shows the html tag. How to load HTML from xhr response just like Android's WebView?

```
WinJS.xhr({ url: uri }).then(function (xhr) {
            if (xhr.status == 200) {
                // Parse xhr to JSON.
                var responseText = xhr.responseText;
                var response = xhr.response;

                // Do something to load responseText in this page.
                // ...
            } else {
                $("#error").text("SOMETHING WRONG");
            }

            return xhr;
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery.ajax({               
                url: 'uri?' + parameter_list,
                success: function(data) {               
                    $("#DivDispSessionDetails").html(data);
                },
                async: true,
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

if you use WinJS.xhr, why don't you use the winjs template system ? ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br229723.aspx ) 
That way, you can encapsulate this query in an object, that update the HTML when ready ( or failed ) 
your HTML will look like :

```
<div class="preview-container" data-win-bind="innerHTML:preview"></div>
</div>
```

where preview contains your html